# In pandas, how do I filter a data frame column to only include values above 9000000 and below 99999909

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where one columns' integer attributes range from 1 to 99999999.

Using pandas, how do I filter that column to only show the specific columns' attributes between 90000000 and 99999999?

Thank you,

Comment: What have you tried / researched already?  Additionally, the values in the question and title are different.  Please clarify the requirement.

Comment: `df[90000000  <= df['columnname'] <= 99999999]`

Comment: @Barmar. While it works very well for python variables, this notation doesn't work with Series.

Answer (score 2):

Use `between`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1, 99999999, 10000)}

>>> df[df['A'].between(90000000, 99999999)]
             A
14    90515447
39    98481777
41    96353791
45    99931205
57    90553633
...        ...
9919  96258260
9926  96892543
9943  99069133
9957  97374508
9980  90698303

[1047 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

data = [
    [1, randint(1, 10)],
    [2, randint(2, 10)],
    [3, randint(90000000,99999999)],
    [4, randint(4, 10)],
    [5, randint(90000000,99999999)]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['1', '2'])
filtered = df[(df.loc[:, '2'] >= 90000000) & (df.loc[:, '2'] <= 99999999)]
print(filtered)
>> 
    1   2
2   3   91196774
4   5   91362223
```